# How to communicate between two containers using docker

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm facing an issue to access one container route in another container. For example i have two micro services called **user-service** and **api-gateway**. I'm trying to access **user-service** route in **api-gateway**.

My **api-gateway** file could be like below

```
  const userServiceProxy = httpProxy(http://localhost:8093);
  this.app.post('/admin/register', async(req, res) => {

      userServiceProxy(req, res);

  });
```

**api-gateway** is running on port 8080

My **user-service** file could be like below

```
 app.post('/admin/register', function (req, res) {
  res.send('POST request')
 })
```

when i access route through **api-gateway** with the port 8080 i couldn't able to call the route but when i tried to access with the port 8093 i can able to see the result.

My **docker-compose** file could be like below

```
 version: '3'
 services:
   api-gateway:
     container_name: api-gateway
     build: './api-gateway'
     ports:
       - "8080:8080"
     links:
       - user-service
   user-service:
     build: ./user-service
     container_name: user-service
     ports:
     - "8093:8093"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the `httpProxy` object?

Comment: when user tried to access the route with port **8080**, which usually redirects to the route to **user service** which is running on port **8093**. By the way i used **express-http-proxy**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`localhost` refers to the localhost inside the container, not the host system.

Use [Docker Networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/) and replace `localhost` with the service name like `api-gateway`.

If the containers are in the same network the address `http://api-gateway:8093`should work.

Another way is to run the Container on network mode `host`. This is less isolation but then the address `localhost` works because the container is now running on the interface of the docker deamon

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Wie ! Can you please suggest me how to use **Docker Networks**?

Comment: sorry I was few days away, @shaped is right with his or her example.

Answer (score 3):

just add a network specification to you docker-compose file to use a custom bridge network.

something like that might work for you

```
version: '3'
services:
  api-gateway:
    container_name: api-gateway
    build: './api-gateway'
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    networks:
    - mynet
  user-service:
    build: ./user-service
    container_name: user-service
    ports:
    - "8093:8093"
    networks:
    - mynet

networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
```

according to your specified ports and services in your docker-compose the following connections are now possible:

- api-gateway container: `user-service:8093`
- user-service container: `api-gateway:8080`

if i get it right, your api-gateway would now be:

```
const userServiceProxy = httpProxy(http://user-service:8093);
  this.app.post('/admin/register', async(req, res) => {
      userServiceProxy(req, res);
  });
```

inside a docker network you can access the ports from other containers directly (no need to specify a port-mapping to your host). probably one of your port-mappings is therefore unnecessary. if you are accessing the user-service only via api-gateway and not directly you may remove the port specification in your docker-compose files (user-service block). your user-service would then be accessible only using the api-gateway. which is probably what you want.

Comment: Many many more thanks to you @shaped ! This is what i was looking for, it worked like champ.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a less known option to connect two or more containers together:

```
version: '3'

services:
  test1:
    image: alpine
    command: nc -lp 1337
  test2:
    image: alpine
    command: nc -lp 1337
    network_mode: service:test1
```

This is similar to internal networking of Kubernetes pods - containers linked this way share the same internal adress (the published ports are visible on localhost and can collide with each other). As a result the above config won't work as there will be a port collision:

```
➜  docker-pod-test docker-compose up
Creating docker-pod-test_test1_1 ... done
Creating docker-pod-test_test2_1 ... done
Attaching to docker-pod-test_test1_1, docker-pod-test_test2_1
test2_1  | nc: bind: Address in use
docker-pod-test_test2_1 exited with code 1
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way would be to use docker flag `--net=host` this way your docker container would be using your host machine's network instead of their own namespaced networks. e.g

```
docker run -d --network host -p 80:80 nginx
```

and you can check on http://localhost for nginx welcome page.

Comment: This exposes all container ports directly on the host, and you lose the isolation that Docker provides.