# container to container localhost connection

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I have exiting vault container :

```
9980675a7704   vault   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 hours ago   Up 4 hours   0.0.0.0:8200->8200/tcp   vault
```

but I could not connect from another web container in the same server through `localhost`:

```
Connect to localhost:8200 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

but I try to `telnet localhost 8200`, it is connected.

Can I use `--link` which is depreciate. Docker-compose network maybe a potential fix, but I need to put everything into one docker-compose file.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this for another question but the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55863061/10962269

`--link` should also work (like a network with with two container), but as you wrote it is deprecated.